# looking for a clean way of how to bring down a ftp server for maintenance

Tags: ftp, maintenance, proftpd

i'm currently thinking of a clean way of how to bring an ftp server down for maintenance. i wonder, if anybody out there could give me some hints of how to solve this:

- i don't want to interrupt any current uploads, but want to block any new connects / uploads and wait, till uploads have finished, before taking down the ftp server
- is there a way of dynamically prevent user-logins and show a message eg.: "ftp currently down for maintenance" when a user tries to log in?

are my thoughts on this very uncommon or how do others handle this -- i feel, that just halting ftp server and killing any current uploads is not the right way for this ...

i use proftpd (with SQL backend) btw, maybe there are some specific solutions for this -- or are there any generic tools to achieve this?

many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [ftpshut](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ftpshut), it's supposed to bring the server down gracefully.  There's an [article here](http://www.castaglia.org/proftpd/doc/contrib/ProFTPD-mini-HOWTO-Stopping.html) about using it with proftpd.

`The ftpshut command provides an automated shutdown procedure that a superuser can use to automagically disconnect current proftpd connections, and deny new connections. The command creates a control file as /etc/shutmsg  to inform proftpd processes about an impending shutdown.`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we need to do work on our FTP servers, we just shut them down (after arranging the downtime internally) - extenal users can resume their uploads when it's back up.

You may be able to find a way to get proftpd to respect /etc/nologin or something like that, but I've never seen anything.

Alternatively, if you have your users stored in a SQL backend, you could stop the SQL server/block the FTP server from talking to the SQL server/change the SQL password/login to prevent new logins.